# Возможно ли сделать следующий эффект?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть слайдер. Слайды с прозрачностью заезжают в монитор.
Возможно ли сделать эффект, чтобы при попадании в монитор слайд терял прозрачность? Не после попадания в монитор, а чтобы та часть, которая в мониторе, была не прозрачной, а часть слайда, которая ещё не успела заехать в монитор, сохраняла прозрачность?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Самый простой вариант - сделать слайды не прозрачными и сказать всем что часть, которая еще не успела заехать в монитор, прозрачная. всё равно этого никто никогда не узнает

Comment: Речь про монитор-картинку. Почему-то картинка из вопроса пропала.

Comment: тогда положите её поверх с полупрозрачным фоном (не будет сильной разницы имхо, делать прозрачный слайд над непрозрачным фоном или наоборот. А там где монитор сделайте полностью прозрачную дырку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот краткая идея того, как можно сделать:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 setInterval(function(){
  var offset = $('#photo').offset().left;
  offset += 5;
  $('#photo').offset({left: offset});
 
 }, 100);
 
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
    border: 1px solid blue;
 position: relative;
 width: 600px;
 height: 200px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#left, #right {
       width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: #fff;
 display: inline-block;
}

#left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

#right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

#photo {
  display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="photo"><img src="http://www.cruzo.net/user/images/k/d760fbd8f50d9b92dc054ee8390df166_617.jpg" alt="" height="150px" id="img"></div>
 <div id="left"></div>
 <div id="right"></div> 
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vpja5wkr/

Анимация на `javascript` там только для того, чтобы показать, что работает))

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так:

```
<div class="slide">
<!--Здесь бэкграундом делаете эффект полупрозрачности(накладываете картинку прозрачную 1 на 1 пиксел и повторение.+z index:2-->
  <div class="monitor">
  <!--Здесь картинка самого монитора.Внутри он должен быть с отверстием равным размеру изображения и ему в стилях создаете позицию абсолют+z-index:3-->
  </div>

  <img src="сам слайд"/><!--Здесь позиция абсолют и z-index:1-->
</div>
```

На js плавно двигаем img меняя их left или right позицию + в divе c классом monitor уже делаем слайд на js.Получится что "прозрачная картинка" будет проходить под монитором,а не прозрачная внутри монитора будет их перекрывать.Главное анимацию попроще выбрать и скорость подобрать

Comment: Что-то у меня есть подозрения, что из этого ничего не выйдет.  Лучше бы вы еще и демо приложили, чтобы показать, что работает